# Why doesn't Virgil have a Sylveon?

Tags: pokemon

Virgil in *Pokémon* is supposed to have every version of Eevee's evolution so why doesn't he have a Sylveon?

[image: Virgil stands in front of a cliff face flanked by 3 others with 6 Eevees in front at different stages of evolution]

Comment: I can't remember the show order, but wasn't it introduced after the episode with Virgil?

Answer (score 3):

That's because Virgil and his team of Eeveelutions appeared in "**Team Eevee and the Pokémon Rescue Squad!**"(November 15, 2012) which was the second episode in the Black & White series.

The Black & White Series was part of Generation 5, Sylveon was introduced in X&Y which is Generation 6 and debuted on October 12 2013, nearly a year later.

So the reason is because the Pokémon did not exist yet. Same reason why the The Battling Eevee Brothers (April 16, 1998) only had Vaporeon, Flareon, Jolteon and Eevee seeing the others did not exist yet.

Comment: And I guess the in-universe explanation is that Sylveon already existed, but Virgil was actually very, very ignorant of Pokemon and didn't know about it.